# How to get the candy machine ID using a NFT created by the candy machine?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, solana, nft, metaplex

Suppose I only have the mint address of a single NFT created by a specific candy machine.
How can I use the mint address and ultimately get the candy machine ID? is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

A fast way to get the CMid using an NFT is fetching the first tx that the NFT has (the oldest one) and checking the fifth instruction, then the first account on this instruction is the Candy Machine used to create and mint the NFT.

For example lets take this NFT `3GXHJJd1DfEn1PVip87uUJXjeW1jDgeJb3B7a6xHWAeJ`, the oldest transaction that is has is [this one](https://explorer.solana.com/address/H2oYLkXdkX38eQ6VTqs26KAWAvEpYEiCtLt4knEUJxpu). Then you can see on the image below that the first account on the 5th instruction is: `H2oYLkXdkX38eQ6VTqs26KAWAvEpYEiCtLt4knEUJxpu` (Note that this CM account is empty because they withdraw and close the account after mint).

[image: Example of fifth instruction on the oldest tx from an NFT with id: 3GXHJJd1DfEn1PVip87uUJXjeW1jDgeJb3B7a6xHWAeJ]

You can do it using some explorer of with code using [solana/web3.js](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTransaction)

Comment: Nice thank you for the response! 
Is there a way to get the first trx quickly ?

Answer (score 0):

as per the official documentation:
https://docs.metaplex.com/guides/mint-lists

> The typical method to create the mint list is to a use a tool that finds all NFTs with a specific creator in the first position of the creators array. If your NFTs were minted with a candy machine this will be the candy machine creator id by default. If you have multiple candy machines that are part of the collection, you can create a separate mint list for each candy machine and combine them together to create a single mint list which you provide to the marketplace(s) you are listing with.

And how to get the creators from a mint address is by getting the metadata associated with the mint address.

The metadata is encoded in a specific format for which you can use the metaplex libraries to decode.
Here is a simple python example: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/issues/48#issuecomment-1073077165

```
def unpack_metadata_account(data):
    assert(data[0] == 4)
    i = 1
    source_account = base58.b58encode(bytes(struct.unpack('<' + "B"*32, data[i:i+32])))
    i += 32
    mint_account = base58.b58encode(bytes(struct.unpack('<' + "B"*32, data[i:i+32])))
    i += 32
    name_len = struct.unpack('<I', data[i:i+4])[0]
    i += 4
    name = struct.unpack('<' + "B"*name_len, data[i:i+name_len])
    i += name_len
    symbol_len = struct.unpack('<I', data[i:i+4])[0]
    i += 4
    symbol = struct.unpack('<' + "B"*symbol_len, data[i:i+symbol_len])
    i += symbol_len
    uri_len = struct.unpack('<I', data[i:i+4])[0]
    i += 4
    uri = struct.unpack('<' + "B"*uri_len, data[i:i+uri_len])
    i += uri_len
    fee = struct.unpack('<h', data[i:i+2])[0]
    i += 2
    has_creator = data[i]
    i += 1
    creators = []
    verified = []
    share = []
    if has_creator:
        creator_len = struct.unpack('<I', data[i:i+4])[0]
        i += 4
        for _ in range(creator_len):
            creator = base58.b58encode(bytes(struct.unpack('<' + "B"*32, data[i:i+32])))
            creators.append(creator)
            i += 32
            verified.append(data[i])
            i += 1
            share.append(data[i])
            i += 1
    primary_sale_happened = bool(data[i])
    i += 1
    is_mutable = bool(data[i])
    metadata = {
        "update_authority": source_account,
        "mint": mint_account,
        "data": {
            "name": bytes(name).decode("utf-8").strip("\x00"),
            "symbol": bytes(symbol).decode("utf-8").strip("\x00"),
            "uri": bytes(uri).decode("utf-8").strip("\x00"),
            "seller_fee_basis_points": fee,
            "creators": creators,
            "verified": verified,
            "share": share,
        },
        "primary_sale_happened": primary_sale_happened,
        "is_mutable": is_mutable,
    }
    return metadata
```

and

```
METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = PublicKey('metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s')
def get_nft_pda(mint_key):
    return(PublicKey.find_program_address([b'metadata', bytes(METADATA_PROGRAM_ID), bytes(PublicKey(mint_key))],METADATA_PROGRAM_ID)[0])
def get_metadata(mint_key):
    data = base64.b64decode(solana_client.get_account_info(get_nft_pda(mint_key))['result']['value']['data'][0])
    return(unpack_metadata_account(data))
```

An example getting Candy Machine ID using this method for the "**Aw4RhpcW5rod2Afhp7dhv2XrMZyNJpzVdYkjJ7kkYzpS**" mint address would result in:

```json
    "update_authority": "DGNZDSvy6emDXvBuCDRrpLVxcPaEcvKiStvvCivEJ38X",
    "mint": "Aw4RhpcW5rod2Afhp7dhv2XrMZyNJpzVdYkjJ7kkYzpS",
    "data": {
        "name": "Shadowy Super Coder #5240",
        "symbol": "SSC",
        "uri": "https://shdw-drive.genesysgo.net/8yHTE5Cz3hwcTdghynB2jgLuvKyRgKEz2n5XvSiXQabG/5240.json",
        "seller_fee_basis_points": 500,
        "creators": [
            "71ghWqucipW661X4ht61qvmc3xKQGMBGZxwSDmZrYQmf",
            "D6wZ5U9onMC578mrKMp5PZtfyc5262426qKsYJW7nT3p"
        ],
        "verified": [
            1,
            0
        ],
        "share": [
            0,
            100
        ]
    },
    "primary_sale_happened": true,
    "is_mutable": true
}
```

In this case, for the Collection SSC, the candy machine ID is **71ghWqucipW661X4ht61qvmc3xKQGMBGZxwSDmZrYQmf**